# JHipster deleting project

Tags: jhipster

I am looking for deleting a full Jhipster project (Cause their system to update entities is terrible, and their system to delete entities is ... non-existant.

Anyway, I would like to go back from 0. Is deleting my project directory enough ?

Won't it makes problems if I `yo generator-jhipster` on another directory after deleting my project's directory ?

Comment: system to delete entities is ... non-existant: this is wrong but you did not ask, same for updating entities

Comment: For updating, I simply used yo jhipster:entity [name] for an existing entity, but when I add a field, I automatically got the Server.Internal Error. :/

If there's a good solution for this, no problem, I take it too :P Is there one for deleting ?

Comment: After updating or creating an entity, you must restart the app. For deleting an entity, you can delete .jhipster/myentity.json file and re-generate your app and entities. Agree this is a workaround , that's why you could request  a new feature to be added to the entity sub generator. See also doc about regenerating all entities: https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/

Comment: I've already seen 2 or 3 topics about adding a deleting feature to JHipster, but still nothing :/ 

Adding an entity create ~20 files, deleting only and and regenerate is enough ?

Comment: A topic is not a feature request, I just created one https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3835

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry I'm a bit new in coding/git/stackoverflow :P

Comment: Well JHipster is not really a tool for beginners, it requires good knowledge of Spring, JPA and ideally angular 1.

Comment: That's what I actually see, but someone at my work recommended it to me for a dynamic display application (I must make an application to display informations on tvs). The principle is easy, but with this tool it's a bit hard :P

Comment: Then why don't you use something else based on a technology stack you master?

Comment: Being a studient, I must do things I don't know :P My project director asked me an application, an engineer said me to try jhipster to gain time, it looks like a really good tool, but I can't ever understand it :P

Comment: Well then take time to train you on Spring Boot, JPA and angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, deleting your project directory is enough, you will not have any problems running "yo jhipster" again.